# Dual boot grub loader 'system setup' option broke everything

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I set up a dual boot windows 10, ubuntu 18.4.3 recently, all worked well.

Out of curiosity I clicked the "system setup" option in grub loader and it took me to the bios -- cool.

But now it will only take me to the bios! even on restart. 
In an atempt to troubleshoot I tried connecting the **same** usb that I intially used to boot up ubuntu and install it. But now UEFI doesn't recognize the usb, and in legacy mode I see the usb name but nothing changes b/c it always boots to the bios. (UEFI/GPT usb btw, FAT32 made with rufus). BTW I have tried both enabling and disabling secure boot and even reset bios settings to default. No good.

I'm not sure how, but simply clicking "system setup" in grub loader has changed something vital.

Prehaps grub loader is working but it goes straight to system setup right away and everytime? Possibly a bug with grub loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally figured out how to fix this. Take out HDD, boot once, then put it back in and reboot everything works like normal again. Still don't understand why or how but I guess my install may be broken or this is a grub bug. I wont dare clicking "system setup" again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're talking about UEFI Boot Order or simply grub boot order. It is because Grub does not include a system setup entry but UEFI Boot Order does. By the way you can use followings to change boot preferences in Grub and UEFI.

**Change Boot Preferences in Grub**

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`

   Find following:

   `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`

   Replace it with following

   `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`
2. Run following command(This assume that grub entry for Ubuntu is named 'Ubuntu', if has some other name, use that)

   `$ sudo grub-set-default 'Ubuntu'`
3. Run following command to update/save grub changes

   `$ sudo update-grub`

**Change Boot Preferences in UEFI**

1. First become super user by using command `sudo su`
2. Now list all UEFI Boot Entries by following command

   `efibootmgr`

   For me, it shows following output

```
BootCurrent: 0000
BootOrder: 0003, 0000
Boot0000: Ubuntu
Boot0003: Windows Boot Manager
```

It clearly shows that I have 0000 for Ubuntu, 0003 for Windows and my boot order is 0003, 0000 so Windows get first preference. I have to load Ubuntu manually from Boot Menu.

3. Note down the 'Boot Number' of 'Ubuntu EFI Boot Entry' and observe all other's numbers. These can be `0000`,`0001`,`0002` etc. Just note boot number not the prefix `Boot`. You have to use these to explicitly change boot order as below.
4. Use following command to change boot order. Here use those boot numbers in sequence to change order. You should type Ubuntu's number first if you want to make that default.

   `efibootmgr -o 0003 0000`

   ***Use your own boot numbers in above, I've used `0003` `0000` as example***

   It say, change efi boot order(`-o` specifies order) to 0003 0000 that mean load Ubuntu(0003) by default.
5. Confirm if boot order has changed by issuing `efibootmgr` command again and restart.

Comment: I can't get out of bios setup mate, this is impossible to do

Comment: @DR.Palson_PH.d Don't use see any Ubuntu entry when entring boot menu? I mean pressing boot menu button as F12 in Dell  and Haier's PC etc, and F10 in some pc's?

Comment: can't see anything in bios nothing works, I see windows boot manager but it doesn't do anything